# Calcular la diferencia de una variable en dos momentos distintos

Tags: c#

Tengo un Acelerómetro que da valores

Me gustaría que cada segundo tome una medida y la compare con la anterior.

Pseudocódigo:

```
Valor1 = Acelerómetro_00:00
Valor2 = Acelerómetro_00:01

Diferencia (Valor2 - Valor1)

If (Valor2 - Valor 1 > 0)
{foo}
Else
{bar}
```

He intentado:

```
if(Time.time % 2 == 0) //cada dos segundos, el módulo vale cero
{Valor2;}
else
{Valor1}
```

Pero esto sobrecarga el programa.

Me gustaría si pudiérais darme alguna orientación de por donde podrían ir los tiros, ya que soy novato y aún me queda por ver mucha documentación

Comment: Has probado a usar un Timer por ejemplo?

Comment: Usé la función Time.time, no sé si eso valdría. Probaré en unos momentos con la respuesta que me brinda el compañero.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que necesitas para calcular diferencias en el tiempo es, el valor a comparar y el momento en que se actualizó por última vez. No necesitas que la frecuencia de actualización sea fija:

```
Diferencia = nuevo_valor - ultimo_valor;
tiempo_pasado = DateTime.Now - ultima_actualizacion;

ultima_actualizacion = DateTime.Now;
nuevo_valor = ultimo_valor;
```

Si lo que necesitas es el cambio por segundo, puedes calcularlo así:

```
var normalizado = Diferencia * (tiempo_pasado.TotalMilliseconds / 1000.0);
```

Para facilitar los cálculos, puedes hacer una clase:

```
class Comparador
{
    private DateTime ultima_actualizacion = default(DateTime);
    private Double ultimo_valor = default(Double);
    private TimeSpan tiempo_pasado = default(TimeSpan);

    public Double Diferencia { get; private set; }
    public TimeSpan DiferenciaTiempo { get { return tiempo_pasado; } }
    public Double DiferenciaNormalizada
    {
        get
        {
            return Diferencia * (tiempo_pasado.TotalMilliseconds / 1000.0);
        }
    }

    public Comparador(Double valor)
    {
        ultimo_valor = valor;
        ultima_actualizacion = DateTime.Now;
    }

    public Double Actualiza(Double nuevo_valor)
    {
        Diferencia = nuevo_valor - ultimo_valor;
        tiempo_pasado = DateTime.Now - ultima_actualizacion;

        ultima_actualizacion = DateTime.Now;
        nuevo_valor = ultimo_valor;
        return Diferencia;
    }
}
```

Que puede usarse así:

```
var RD = new Random();
var RI = new Random();
Double valor = RD.NextDouble();
var c = new Comparador(valor);

for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    Thread.Sleep(RI.Next(111, 1111));
    Console.Write(String.Format("Valor actual {0}", valor));
    c.Actualiza(valor = RD.NextDouble());
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format(" valor nuevo {0} ({1} transcurridos).", valor, c.DiferenciaTiempo));
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("La diferencia es {0} (normalizada a segundos {1}).", c.Diferencia, c.DiferenciaNormalizada));
}
```

Puedes verlo funcionando en [rextester](https://rextester.com/OXK79307).

Comment: Yo creo que la pregunta de OP va mas por el tema de bloquear el UI (algo que creo que con Thread.Sleep en tu ejemplo también sucedería). Pero a ver si nos lo aclara el mismo :)

Comment: El *sleep* está puesto para que la prueba de la clase `Comparador` tenga sentido, forma parte del ejmplo de uso, no es que espere que vaya  parar al código final que el usuario necesita.

Comment: Perdonad mi nivel ultranovato; donde sustituiría en este código mis valores recibidos por el acelerómetro. (Los he alojado en una variable llamada "EulerAnglesX")

Comment: Si, eso entendí. Pero lo aclaro porque me parece que el OP el principal problema que tiene es bloqueo de UI (_Pero esto sobrecarga el programa._)

Comment: Os agradezco muchísimo la ayuda, pero no sé que significa "bloqueo de UI"; supongo que tiene que ver con Thread.Sleep

Comment: @albertogo1989 nos es completa y absolutamente imposible saber dónde debes poner código porque desconocemos por completo tu código. En general y arriesgándome mucho, yo crearía una instancia de `Comparador` dentro de la clase que use el acelerómetro y si dicha clase tiene una función que se llama periódicamente (un `Update` o algo así) llamaría al `Actualiza` de la instancia de `Comparador`.

Comment: Vale, después de haberlo pensado, creo que me podría valer que, en vez de "valor", usar ahí mis valores del acelerómetro. Y el valor de la diferencia es el que usaré en mi código. Si lo acabo satisfactoriamente, lo subiré en una respuesta. Gracias una vez más.